# Magento / Nginx - subdirectory multistore

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I have been looking through so many articles on this but nothing is helping!

I have installed a vanilla magento instance on Redhat with Nginx.   The base store is working as expected but when I try to run a separate website which is configured using a sub directory "/privatesales".

my nginx/conf.d/sitename.conf contains:

```
server {
listen 192.168.01; ##changed for security
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
ssl_session_timeout 7m;
## Specify your SSL options here
ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log /var/log/nginx/vanillamagento.local-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/vanillamagento.local-error.log;

server_name vanilla.domain.com;
root /var/www/vanillamagento/magento;
include conf/vanillamagento_rewrites.conf;
include conf/vanillamagento_security.conf;

# PHP handler
location ~ \.php {
  ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
  if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

  ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
##  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
 ## fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

  # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
  include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
}

# 404s are handled by front controller
location @magefc {
  rewrite / /index.php;
}

# Last path match hands to magento or sets global cache-control
location / {
  ## Maintenance page overrides front controller
  index index.html index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @magefc;
  expires 24h;
}
}
```

I have tried the following methods to get this to work:

1 - Adding switch function in index.php

```
$host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
switch ($host[0]) {
case 'vanilla.domain.com/privatesales':
  $store = 'private';
  $type = 'website';
  break;

default:
  $store = 'base';
  $type = 'store';
}
```

2 - Adding the following into nginx config (conf/vanillamagento_rewrites.conf) and then symlinking the /privatesales directory to the webroot

```
location ~* \.php$ {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite / /index.php last;
}
expires off;
set $runcode default;
set $runtype store;
if ( $request_uri ~* ^/privatesales) {
        set $runcode private;
        set $runtype website;
}
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $runcode;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $runtype;
include fastcgi_params;
 }
```

Just not having much luck and have been trying to fix this for 2 days :P.  Thanks!

Comment: What you ask for sounds like a configuration question about some specific software. Please contact the vendor of that software for you support options and/or consult a Q&A website that is dedicated to that software (Stackoverflow is about *Programming* questions as outlined in the FAQ).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a third party software, here namely Magento.


Answer (score 2):

got it working finally!  You have to modify the URL after switching! Add the following to your index.php:

```
$host = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//print_r($host); die();
switch ($host[1]) {
case 'privatesales':
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=str_replace("/privatesales","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$mageRunCode  = "privatesales";
$mageRunType = "store";
 //$store = 'privatesales';
 //$type = 'website';
 break;

default:
$mageRunCode = 'default';
$mageRunType = 'store';
break;
}
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```